# How to find what programs are reading my file?

Tags: linux, files, monitoring, lsof

I have a configuration file and want to learn what executables are using it (if any).  I want to catch who is the reader of this file.

If I `watch` with some interval, I miss it, because the read happens so quickly:

```
watch -d -n 1 "lsof /home/me/my.conf"
```

If I try to execute the program I'm pretty sure uses it under the auspices of `strace`, it fails because of the additional delay `strace` introduces.

```
strace -o /tmp/$(date +%s)_myprog.trace myprog
```

How can I reliably prove that `myprog` is NOT reading this file?

Comment: This sounds like a variation of _the halting problem_.

Comment: @Kusalananda, in this case, I only need to search for the first 10 or so seconds after starting `myprog`.

Comment: This might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9614184/how-to-trace-per-file-io-operations-in-linux

Comment: This question does not seem a duplicate of that particular question. This question is about realtime debugging, the old question mentions finding out if a file was accessed in the last few days. While some answers will overlap, there will be different strategies and answers.

Answer (score 9):

Watching what files a process open, or what processes open a file seems a job for `sysdig`.

From the [sysdig examples page](https://github.com/draios/sysdig/wiki/Sysdig-Examples)

> Basic opensnoop: snoop file opens as they occur
>
> ```
> sysdig -p "%12user.name %6proc.pid %12proc.name %3fd.num %fd.typechar %fd.name" evt.type=open
> ```
>
> Observe the I/O activity on all files named my.conf
>
> ```
> sysdig -A -c echo_fds "fd.filename=my.conf"
> ```

Fom [man sysdig](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/sysdig.8.html)

> NAME
>          sysdig - the definitive system and process troubleshooting tool
>
> SYNOPSIS
>          sysdig [option]...  [filter]
>
> DESCRIPTION.
>
> ```
>    sysdig is a tool for  system  troubleshooting,  analysis  and  explo‐
>    ration.   It  can  be used to capture, filter and decode system calls
>    and other OS events.
>    sysdig can be both used to inspect live systems, or to generate trace
>    files that can be analyzed at a later stage.
>
>    sysdig  includes  a powerul filtering language, has customizable out‐
>    put, and can be extended through Lua scripts, called chisels.
> ```